# .htaccess Skipping Redirects

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess which works on multiple domains on the same host however I seem to be having an issue with one domain.  It appears to skip the rerwrite conditions and skips directly to the ErrorDocument.  The ErrorDocument works fine and displays 404.  I tried removing the IfModule wrap with no success.  Is there anything else I can do or try?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]*)
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*))?(/([^/]*)) /$1.php?ax=$3&do=$5&third=$7&fourth=$9 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/(.*)$ /content.php?url=$1/$2 [L]
    
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /content.php?url=404
```

Comment: "I tried removing the IfModule wrap with no success" - And "no success" is no error, just nothing happens? What version of Apache are you on? And this "one domain" is on the same host as all the other domains (that is working)? What URL are you requesting?